# Using Portable git and ssh with Openshift's rhc Windows

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

I use a portable installation of Git on my Windows. To be able to call 'git' from anywhere, I have added it's directory to the PATH. 
Now when I use rhc git-clone, it shows this error

```
You do not have git installed. In order to fully interact with OpenShift you will need to install and configure a git client. We recommend this free application: Git for Windows - a basic git command line and GUI client <mysysgit link>
```

Same happens for ssh.

Is there any way I can config rhc to use custom executables ?

Comment: I noticed there is [Bug Report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1294401) for this on Bugzilla.